# routing issue in reactjs where the matchUrl is coming from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am facing this issue in routing in react .
One of the Component gets loaded on the screen and threre are various routes inside it .

Here is the code inside return in that component .

```
   <Route
            path={`/cricket/tournament/${matchId}/standings`}
            render={routeProps =>
              isFetchingMatchDetail ? (
                <Loading />
              ) : (
                <Standings {...routeProps} tournamentId={tournamentId}
                  matchSummary={detailsData && detailsData.matchSummary} />
              )
            }
          />
```

and on change of tab ,I am doing this .

```
    const standingpath=`/cricket/tournament/${matchId}/standings`;
    this.props.history.push(standingpath);
```

But i don't see my standing component loading .The tab and the routing are in the same component .
Here is another route inside same return which works fine .

```
       <Route
            path={matUrl + "/scorecard"}
            render={routeProps =>
              isFetchingMatchDetail ? (
                <Loading />
              ) : (
                <Scorecard
                  {...routeProps}
                  matchId={matchId}
                  innings={innings}
                  matchInfo={matchInfo}
                  matchSummary={detailsData && detailsData.matchSummary}
                />
              )
            }
          />
```

where matchUrl is coming as props .

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure `isFetchingMatchDetail` related condition is working fine.
2. in react, the syntax is

```js
<Route
    path='/cricket/tournament/:matchId/standings'
    render={routeProps =>
    isFetchingMatchDetail ? (
        <Loading />
    ) : (
        <Standings 
          {...routeProps} 
          tournamentId={tournamentId}
          matchSummary={detailsData && detailsData.matchSummary} />
          )
        }
/>
```

Comment: Hey.isFetching is not as issue .,I think it may be happening because of some other reason .

Comment: check react-router documentation it passes path like in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Route's path to `path={'/cricket/tournament/:matchId/standings'}`

Comment: I agree with ManavM. It looks like you problem is here `path={`/cricket/tournament/${matchId}/standings`}`
Check [react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web) how to pass url parameters to `Route`